# Why would a router not connect on its fastest mode?

Tags: networking, mac, wireless-networking, wireless-router, 802.11ac

I have an Airport Extreme router that can connect to devices on 802.11ac mode, if the devices support it. My MacBook Air, which supports `ac` mode, seems to be connected on `n` mode. Here is the information from the Mac's Wi-Fi menu:

[image]

Why would a router which supports a Wi-Fi standard not connect to a device which also supports this standard, with the fastest mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the broadcast range on [this site](https://www.apple.com/airport-extreme/), it appears that if you are more than 20 feet from the router, the speed decreases drastically. If the distance is far enough, the 802.11ac would be slower than the 802.11n since the 5GHz frequency (for 802.11ac) has a shorter range than the 2.4GHz frequency (for 802.11n).

> So no matter which band your wireless devices use, they’ll automatically connect to the best available band for the fastest possible performance.

If you are only 5 feet  from the router, I would think there might be a problem with the router or wireless connection in the computer.

Comment: Are you talking about the beamforming illustration? That's just intended to give you an idea of how beamforming works. The circles should not be taken literally. But it's true that you can't get the 1300 Mbps PHY rate at the far reaches of any AP's range, and starting somewhere around halfway to the edge of a simultaneous dual-band AP's range, 2.4GHz will typically get better performance than 5GHz, so smart clients will prefer 2.4GHz at those ranges.

Comment: @Spiff Yes, I know the illustration is inaccurate, but I was hoping the distance I mentioned was far enough to have a noticeable drop in speed.